# How to update gps coordinates onMapReady?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm using google maps on my app. The method `onMapReady` has build in laltitude and longitude. My question is if I can change these coordinates in the method.
What I'm trying to do is in my activity I'm getting broadcast receiver with the coordinates. then I want to update these coordinates in the method `onMapReady`
so it will show me the current location.

**GPS Activity**

```
   public class GPS extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback , Listen {

   private Button startGPS,stopGPS;
   private TextView addresTv;
   private GoogleMap mMap;
   private GPSTurnOnOff gpsTurnOnOff;
   private IntentFilter mIntent;
   private BroadcastReceiver GPSBroadcast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mIntent = new IntentFilter("BroadcastGPS");

            GPSBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String latitude = intent.getStringExtra("LATITUDE");
            String longitude = intent.getStringExtra("LONGITUE");
        }
    };
  }

         /**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

---

how can i enter to this line **LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);** the new coordinates that received from the broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Use can use global mMap (GoogleMap) object

```
 GPSBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String latitude = intent.getStringExtra("LATITUDE");
        String longitude = intent.getStringExtra("LONGITUE");
        if(mMap != null){
            // Do what you want here
            // mMap.addMarker(...);
            // mMap.moveCamera(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean **private GoogleMap googleMap** and then use it on onReceive as a global object?